# How to keep track of how many items in a list are greater than the head element in prolog

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

I'm looking to keep track of how many items in a given list are greater than the head element. I've tried using an increment relation as well as tried to build a new list with the elements that are greater but I've had no success. This is what I've been working with:

```
pullHead([H|T]) :-
    isGreater(H,T).

isGreater(X,[H|T]) :-
    X > H -> inc(Count,Temp),
    isGreater(X,T);
    isGreater(X,T).

inc(X,Y) :-
    X is Y+1.
```

OR

```
pullHead([H|T]) :-
        isGreater(H,T).
    
isGreater(X,[H|T]) :-
        X > H -> append(X,List,List),
        isGreater(X,T);
        isGreater(X,T).
    
length(List,Count).
```

My goal is to have the number of elements greater than the head stored in Count.

```
Example: List = [4,7,0,8,1,2,3]
         Count = 2
```

I've gone through the prolog dev pages to try and understand how to make something like this work but to no avail. I'm not quite sure if I'm going about creating a new list the right way. It seems like these relations should work but there must be some issue with the correct allocation of variables or in the recursive calls?

Comment: Can you provide an example input / desired ouput?

Comment: yes I edited the original post @damianodamiano

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
% The "entry predicate"

occurrences_greater_than_head([LV|Xs],N) :-   
   ogth_2(Xs,LV,0,N).

% The "entry predicate" calls a helper predicate
% having three "input parameters"
%
% +List, +LimitValue, +Counter
%
% and a "I/O parameter" that can be passed in (then the predicate
% verifies its value) or left unbound, in which case it will be
% bound to a numeric value that is the sought result:
%
% ?Limit.
%
% That is to say, the intended use of the predicate is:
%
% ogth_2(+List,+LimitValue,+Counter,?Result).
%
% It recurses through List, increasing Counter as it goes (an
% "accumulator values") and unifies the Counter with Result when the
% end of the list has been reached, thus communicating the final
% count to the original caller.

ogth_2([],_,C,C).         % end case: unify Counter and Result

ogth_2([X|Xs],LV,C,R) :-  % Case of:
   X =< LV,               % "smaller"  
   ogth_2(Xs,LV,C,R).     % There is nothing to do here; call yourself
                          % with a smaller list and the same C

ogth_2([X|Xs],LV,C,R) :-  % Case of:
   X > LV,                % "larger"  
   CN is C+1,             % Actual arithmetic evaluation
   ogth_2(Xs,LV,CN,R).    % Call yourself with smaller list and CN,
                          % thus the C in the next activation will be CN
```

Comment: This seems like it should accomplish what I'm looking for. For a better understanding of lists as well, would you be able to recursively call this on the tail and find the number of elements greater than the second element and so on? @DavidTonhofer

Comment: @JoshPokorny as in `occurrences_greater_than_head_plus_3([_,_,_,LV|Xs],N) :- ogth_2(Xs,LV,0,N).` for example? This will just discard the first three elements. But then you can do `for_all_occurrences_greater_than_head_plus_3([A0,A1,A2,LV|Xs],N) :- ogth_2([A0,A1,A2|Xs],LV,0,N).`